# Convert xml string to XML document in Internet Explorer - C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have converted a table as an xml string that looks something like

```
  <NewDataSet>\r\n <officelist>\r\n <OfficeID>2176</OfficeID>\r\n 
<Office>My Office </Office>\r\n <Region>Toronto</Region>\r\n 
<Division>TO </Division>\r\n
```

How do I get this to a strict xml page where you can open and close the nodes (in IE) –
[like this xml feed](http://dir.gigablast.com/Top?raw=9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I just used loadxml to load the string. Somehow i forgot about this

```
doc.LoadXml(xmlDS);
        doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the Response.ContentType to "text/xml"